# Is it possible to order/configure IBM SoftLayer file storage using slcli or Python API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to order file storage using either the SoftLayer CLI `slcli` or the Python API?

I can list the file storage in my account, but I do not see any sub-commands for ordering new storage or authorizing hosts.

```
slcli nas

Usage: slcli nas [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Network Attached Storage.

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  credentials  List NAS account credentials.
  list         List NAS accounts.
```

I cannot find a way using the [Python API](http://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/) either.

Am I forced to use the SoftLayer web portal, or is there a hidden API somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, while the script above works for storage 1000GB and higher, see this answer for storage less than 1000GB.
[What are valid IOPS values for ordering File Storage via the SoftLayer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333361/what-are-valid-iops-values-for-ordering-file-storage-via-the-softlayer-api)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the script at the above link to order performance NFS storage.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is not that option in the SLCLI you have to make api calls to create the file storage take a look this example:

```
"""
Order a file storage (performance NFS).

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Nfs
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3
http://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274081
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Values "AMS01", "AMS03", "CHE01", "DAL05", "DAL06" "FRA02", "HKG02", "LON02", etc.
location = "set me"

# Values "20", "40", "80", "100", etc.
storageSize = "set me"

# Values between "100" and "6000" by intervals of 100.
iops = "set me"

PACKAGE_ID = 222

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
productOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
locationGroupService = client['SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing']
locationService = client['SoftLayer_Location']

objectFilterDatacenter = {"name": {"operation": location.lower()}}
objectFilterStorageNfs = {"items": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_nfs"}}}}
objectMaskLocation = "mask[locations]"

try:
    # Getting the datacenter.
    datacenter = locationService.getDatacenters(filter=objectFilterDatacenter)
    # Getting the performance storage NFS prices.
    itemsStorageNfs = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilterStorageNfs)
    # Getting the SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing which contains the configured location.
    locations = locationGroupService.getAllObjects(mask=objectMaskLocation)
    for item in locations:
        for loc in item['locations']:
            if location.lower() == loc['name'].lower():
                location = item
                break
        if 'id' in location:
            break
    # Getting the storage space prices which match the configured storage space, and are valid for the configured location.
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location, we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    pricesStorageSpace = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(pricesStorageSpace) == 0:
        objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        pricesStorageSpace = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is still empty that means that the storage space value is invalid.
    if len(pricesStorageSpace) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The storage space value: ' + storageSize + ' GB, is not valid.')
    # Getting the IOPS prices which match the configured IOPS, are valid for the configured storage space, and are valid for the configured location.
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location, we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    pricesIops = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(pricesIops) == 0:
        objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        pricesIops = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is still empty that means that the IOPS value is invalid for the configured storage space.
    if len(pricesIops) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The IOPS value: ' + iops + ', is not valid for the storage space: ' + storageSize + ' GB.')
    # Building the order template.
    orderData = {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Nfs",
        "packageId": PACKAGE_ID,
        "location": datacenter[0]['id'],
        "quantity": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": itemsStorageNfs[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesStorageSpace[0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesIops[0]['id']
            }
        ],
    }
    # verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
    # placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
    # that you can use for your records.
    response = productOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
    print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to place the order. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```