# What are valid IOPS values for ordering File Storage via the SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

While attempting to use the Python script provided as the answer for [Is it possible to order/configure IBM SoftLayer file storage using slcli or Python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217768/is-it-possible-to-order-configure-ibm-softlayer-file-storage-using-slcli-or-pyth), I keep getting the following error:

"ValueError: The IOPS value: 125, is not valid for the storage space: 500GB."

I got this error for IOPS values of 100, 125, 200, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 2500, 3000, 5000 and 6000.

I am trying this for the San Jose data center (sjc01).

What is the valid value for IOPS for 500GB of file storage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395860/no-data-for-iops-while-selecting-storage-size-250gb-or-500gb-in-performance-stor?noredirect=1#comment61009305_36395860), The filter, to get the IOPS prices, uses the configured storage space, it fails when you use a storage space less than 1000, in order to avoid the error the code needs to use in its request "1000" as storage space to get the valid pricesfor IOPS. In the code below I added that scenerio.

The another error is that the IOPS must be in increased in intervals of 100. In another words the value "125" is invalid. You need to change it to "100" or "200"

Regards

```
"""
Order a file storage (performance NFS).

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Nfs
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3
http://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274081
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Values "AMS01", "AMS03", "CHE01", "DAL05", "DAL06" "FRA02", "HKG02", "LON02", etc.
location = "set me"

# Values "20", "40", "80", "100", etc.
storageSize = "set me"

# Values between "100" and "6000" by intervals of 100.
iops = "set me"

PACKAGE_ID = 222

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
productOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
locationGroupService = client['SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing']
locationService = client['SoftLayer_Location']

objectFilterDatacenter = {"name": {"operation": location.lower()}}
objectFilterStorageNfs = {"items": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_nfs"}}}}
objectMaskLocation = "mask[locations]"

try:
    # Getting the datacenter.
    datacenter = locationService.getDatacenters(filter=objectFilterDatacenter)
    # Getting the performance storage NFS prices.
    itemsStorageNfs = packageService.getItems(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilterStorageNfs)
    # Getting the SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing which contains the configured location.
    locations = locationGroupService.getAllObjects(mask=objectMaskLocation)
    for item in locations:
        for loc in item['locations']:
            if location.lower() == loc['name'].lower():
                location = item
                break
        if 'id' in location:
            break
    # Getting the storage space prices which match the configured storage space, and are valid for the configured location.
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location, we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        objectFilterNoLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    pricesStorageSpace = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(pricesStorageSpace) == 0:
        objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation":  storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        pricesStorageSpace = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is still empty that means that the storage space value is invalid.
    if len(pricesStorageSpace) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The storage space value: ' + storageSize + ' GB, is not valid.')
    # Getting the IOPS prices which match the configured IOPS, are valid for the configured storage space, and are valid for the configured location.
    # In case we did not get a location group for the configured location, we are going to search for standard prices.
    if 'id' in location:
        objectFilterLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "in", "options": [{"name": "data", "value": [location['id']]}]}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterLocation
    else:
        if (int(storageSize) < 1000):
            objectFilterNoLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": "1000"}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        else:
            objectFilterNoLocation = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        objectFilter = objectFilterNoLocation
    pricesIops = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    if len(pricesIops) == 0:
        if (int(storageSize) < 1000):
            objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": "1000"}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        else:
            objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"item": {"capacity": {"operation": iops}}, "attributes": {"value": {"operation": storageSize}}, "categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_iops"}}, "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"}}}
        pricesIops = packageService.getItemPrices(id=PACKAGE_ID, filter=objectFilter)
    # If the prices list is still empty that means that the IOPS value is invalid for the configured storage space.
    if len(pricesIops) == 0:
        raise ValueError('The IOPS value: ' + iops + ', is not valid for the storage space: ' + storageSize + ' GB.')
    # Building the order template.
    orderData = {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Nfs",
        "packageId": PACKAGE_ID,
        "location": datacenter[0]['id'],
        "quantity": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": itemsStorageNfs[0]['prices'][0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesStorageSpace[0]['id']
            },
            {
                "id": pricesIops[0]['id']
            }
        ],
    }
    # verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
    # placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
    # that you can use for your records.
    response = productOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
    print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to place the order. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```